# How to update certain column in sql using select and where clause on the same table?

Tags: mysql

I have a table called `employeepostinghistory` with the following columns:
employee_posting_id, employee_posting_to, employee_posting_from, emp_emp_cnic

`employee_posting_id` is primary key and `emp_emp_cnic` is foreign key

Basically this table is responsible to hold employee history with from and to dates i.e. employee_posting_from and employee_posting_to.

I want to update all records setting employee_posting_to=NULL Where employee history is latest so, I have used DESC on employee_posting_from. But, UPDATE query says subquery return more than 1 record, What can be the possible solution for this problem.

```
UPDATE employeepostinghistory 
SET employeepostinghistory.posting_to=NULL 
WHERE employeepostinghistory.emp_emp_cnic=(
    SELECT DISTINCT employeepostinghistory.emp_emp_cnic 
    from employeepostinghistory  
    GROUP BY employeepostinghistory.emp_emp_cnic 
    ORDER BY employeepostinghistory.posting_from DESC
    )
;
```

Comment: Your subquery really returns a lot of rows - you may execute the subquery separately and ensure.

Comment: #1. DISTINCT and GROUP BY at the same time is excess. In this particular case - remove GROUP BY. #2. ORDER BY will be ignored and hence is excess - remove it or add LIMIT.

Comment: *Where employee history is latest* - what is "latest"? in what group? by what criteria?

Comment: latest means where posting_from is the most recent date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
UPDATE employeepostinghistory 
NATURAL JOIN ( 
    SELECT emp_emp_cnic, MAX(datetime_column) datetime_column
    FROM employeepostinghistory 
    GROUP BY 1 
    ) last_row_per_employee
SET employeepostinghistory.posting_to=NULL 
;
```

`emp_emp_cnic.datetime_column` must be unique.